# How to change the page url

Tags: backbone.js

I am building a shopping cart using backbone.js . When some one clicks on 'add to cart' I am making an ajax call using jQuery. Backend is rails. In response I get the new json value for the cart. However if I display the cart view then car view comes up , however the url does not change.

To make the url change I after receiving the response from jQuery I need to do something so that router catches the new url and things proceed from there.

How do I navigate to the `#cart` url?

Answer (score 25):

You can update the URL by calling the navigate method on your router, like this:

```
router.navigate('cart');
```

Comment: Make sure read up on routers, http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Router "During page load, after your application has finished creating all of its routers, be sure to call Backbone.history.start(), or Backbone.history.start({pushState: true}) to route the initial URL."

Comment: be sure to run `router.navigate('cart', {trigger: true, replace: true});` if you want it to run the route function and replace the URL. (trigger option for the function and replace option for the replacing the URL)

Answer (score 10):

Most likely your view doesn't have access to the router you can do this:

```
Backbone.history.navigate('cart', {trigger:true});  // router handles view change


Backbone.history.navigate('cart');                  // only url is updated
```